# File manager which is able to filter using regular expressions

Tags: software-rec, regular-expression, file-manager

Is there any graphical file-manager which supports thumbnails for linux like thunar or nautilus, which allows me to filter a directory by a regular expression. For example typing `/home/user/*tex` should show all tex-files, or `[AB].*` all files starting with A or B etc.

Comment: Just for the record, `/home/user/*tex` is not a regular expression which matches all `tex` files—you have likely confused shell globbing with regexps. Your example matches `/home/usertex`, `/home/user/tex`, `/home/user//tex`, etc. If you want to match all `tex` files in this manner, the regex would be something like `/home/user/.*tex` (note that this would match tex files in a subdirectory as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `midnight-commander`, which is a kind of hybrid between graphical and text based, supports globbing, which is, what you show in your examples.

Therefor, filemanagers which claim to be graphical versions of `midnight-commander` (Krusador?) should be able to do it.

A difference between globbing and regex is, for example

```
 foo*bar in regex means foobar, fooobar, foooooooobar etc.
 foo*bar in globbing means foo.bar fooxbar, all of the above.
```

`[AB]` means the same, but a dot is a wildcard here, and a dot there.

```
 ca[nt].png  matches cat.png and can.png in both cases, 
 but catopng only as regex.
```

A single wildcard character in globbing is ?: `ca?` is for example cat, can, car and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Pcmanfm allow you to filter the view. Try to press ctrl + e 
then if you write *.tex you see only tex file like when you use the ls command.

Comment: That is not a regular expression. That is simply an example of shell globbing.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find on Wikipedia a [complete list of file managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_managers#Search_features), with a detailed comparison of what search/regexp features they offers. You'll have to cross-results with *nix-compatible ones, though.

It seems that at least Konqueror and Dolphin support regexp and thumbnails.